# Grammatical emphasis

Tags: grammar

When we want to write strong statements like one sentence thesis, which conjunctions or linking words make the sentence seem more convincing?
For instance, would saying "but" instead of "yet" be stronger?

Other thing that, I use "although" a lot to say that I agree with something partially, but I also mention new aspect that it contradicts a bit.
I said a bit because I don't want strong ones like "but".
Can you give me other words as alternative?

I give an example:

> Technological developments have made life easier in many ways; however, what some people think as a disadvantage is these devices emit hazardous rays that harm our health, especially children who use them much more. **Nevertheless**, in terms of education, technology has a significant role on children’s intellectual development that cannot be ignored.

Now, I used "nevertheless" instead of "although".  Is that correct ?

Comment: You didn't use "nevertheless" instead of "although"; if you used "although" there it wouldn't have made very much sense. You correctly used nevertheless to introduce a point or argument that contrasts with the previous point or argument. It is a way of drawing attention to that contrast, making clear that it is deliberate. Well, it doesn't contrast that much; it would do so better if it were actually positive, rather than neutral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand, you are asking two separate questions.

First, you ask if using *but* instead of *yet* as a conjunction is 'stronger'. The answer is no. There is no inherent 'strength' in either of these words. They are interchangeable when used as conjunctions. Both can be used in ways in which they are not interchangeable ('none but the brave', 'he hasn't finished yet'), but in common use they are synonyms.

Second, you ask if *although* or *nevertheless* was correct. In the context of the sentence you provided, *nevertheless* is correct. *Nevertheless* is an adverb; *although* is a conjunction. You could have used *although*, but you would, in effect, have been creating one very long run-on sentence, regardless of whether you used a full-stop/period before it or not. *Nevertheless* was the better choice as it meant you created a proper new sentence.

It is quite difficult to spot that *nevertheless* is an adverb, above all because it does not end in the usual '-ly', but it does in fact modify the verb 'role' in your sentence. Consider:

> Technology has a role, nevertheless, in children's education.

You can see more clearly here that 'nevertheless' relates to the verb 'role'. It is not joining two related but separate parts of sentence like a conjunction does. You could take out 'nevertheless' and you'd have one simple sentence.

With a conjunction, you need to have the 'other part' of the sentence that it is linking to.

> Although technology has a role in children's education, ... [the other part of the sentence is required here for it to make sense].

Furthermore, while it is not accurate to say (as many pedants used to) that 'you can't start a sentence with a conjunction', a sentence with a conjunction does have to link to another clause or immediately preceding sentence in an obvious way. For the purposes of an English language learner, one might be better to pretend that the old 'rule' still holds. Avoid starting sentences with conjunctions unless you're sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: I think your first example might be confusing, as the sentence can not stand on its own.  The "nevertheless" necessarily refers to some previous contradictory statement, and so I'm not sure why it's not a conjunction in this context, e.g. *"It's important that young children receive personal attention from live human teachers as possible; **nevertheless** there is a role for technology in children's education"*.  The dictionary does categorize it as an adverb, but I think it's a particle of various uses.

Comment: To an extent the distinction is very minor. But sentences refer to other sentences all the time, and 'need' them to complete the sense that is being conveyed. That does not mean that they have to be part of other sentences. That's the role of a paragraph. 'Nevertheless' is behaving in a way that is very similar to, but not the same as, a conjunction, as can be seen from the ability to use it in the way I did in my first example. (I'm not saying it's the best way to write the sentence, just that it works.) You can't do that with a conjunction.